# VHDL calculations inside a function

Tags: vhdl

I want to write a function that returns `mod 100`.
What's wrong with code below?

```
subtype int is integer range 0 to 255;
function div(val : int) return int is 
    variable result : int;
    variable number : int;
begin
    result := 0;
    number := val;
    while number >= 100 loop
        result := result + 1;
        number := number - 100;
    end loop;
    return result;
end div;
```

Comment: there is nothing "wrong" with it, assuming you only ever want to return the values 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: I know, but my input is 200 and it returns 0

Comment: Tricky's comment is valid (and the function could be implemented with an if statement instead of a loop). Your comment `I know, but my input is 200 and it returns 0 – KARO3213 16 hours ago` isn't sustained by [an implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wliqM.jpg). absent you providing a [mcve] demonstrating a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:** extend the answer to be more understandable.*

In your function you return the quotient that is counted in `result`, not the remainder that is left in `number`. But this is what I would expect from a function named `div()`.

If you want to return the remainder, you can use the same code, but change the last line into

```
return number;
```

And I would rename this new function to `mod()`.

Comment: The remainder would be in `number` while the quotient is the `result`.

Comment: That is what I wrote, isn't it? However, the name of the function will be misleading... Editing my answer. ;-)